# Every permutation from two tables

Tags: database

Im using Access 2010.

I have two tables Region which holds 27 regions and product which holds 75 product_Id's.

I would like to build a query to assign every region to each individual product_id.

Regions
Africa
Europe
India

Product
2020015
1546873
5554449

Results
Africa 2020015
Africa 1546873
Africa 5554449
Europe 2020015
Europe 1546873
Europe 5554449
India  2020015
India  1546873
India  5554449

I have no idea how I would even start to build a query to do this can anyone point me in the right direction please.

Answer (score -1):

FOUND IT UIT WAS MUCH EASIER THAN i THOUGHT HAHA

SELECT DISTINCT Region.Region, MarketingGroup.[Parent]
FROM MarketingGroup INNER JOIN Region ON MarketingGroup.Region = Region.Region;